# Can not find BibTex using TexShop

Tags: bibtex, texshop

I'm relatively new to LaTex and I want to use a BibTex file. I read online to build in the following sequence: latex, bibtex, latex, latex. I tried this, but it is still not working.

When running the BibTex file, the console gives me the following error:

```
I couldn't open file name `bib.aux'
```

I am using TexShop on Mac. In my files I have the following:

**Tex file:**

```
\bibliography{bib}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
```

**Bib file:**

```
@BOOK{DUMMY:1,
      AUTHOR="John Doe",
      TITLE="The Book Without Title",
      PUBLISHER="Dummy Publisher",
      YEAR="2014",
}
```

Comment: You do not run bibtex on the .bib file, but on the .aux file that results from the (pdf)latex compilation of your main document. It is this file that contains all useful information for bibtex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) If Bernard's comment doesn't resolve the issue, please help us to help you and add a [minimal non-working example (MnWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.